# Why was Character.isAlphabetic() added in Android API level 19?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a simple text analyzing method and have a min SDK version set to 11. And just now I found out that the minimum API level for `Character.isAlphabetic()` is 19. As long as I remember Character class is a standart Java class that has been added a long long time ago. So why is it working this way? How is it better to replace it?

P.S. I haven't tested my app on a lower api level so I am not sure yet if it's working on <19.

Comment: Only the Android dev team can answer this.

Comment: @Henry well yeah, that's definitely true. But I hope that some other users have encountered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the function only entered java in version 1.7, and Jellybean was not built against Java version 1.6.

Character.isLetter() checks whether the character is in a-z or A-Z --which is different but may work for some use cases.

There's an old blog post that talks about how the Jellybean sources do not compile the same for Java 1.7 here:

http://blog.klocwork.com/android-development/use-the-correct-java-jdk-for-android-builds/